# Show that $\operatorname{Spec}A$ is the disjoint union of open (and closed) subspaces $X_i$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> Let $A = \prod_{i=1}^n A_i$ be the direct product of rings $A_i$. Show that $\operatorname{Spec}A$ is the disjoint union of open (and closed) subspaces $X_i$, where $X_i$ is canonically homeomorphic with $\operatorname{Spec} A_i$.

This question was on Atiyah & Macdonald's introduction to commutative algerba. I'm having trouble understanding how to approach the problem. Clearly they want me to show the equality $$\operatorname{Spec} A= \bigsqcup_{i=1}^n X_i$$ so doing both inclusion would satisfy. However if I pick $\mathfrak p \in \operatorname{Spec}A$, then I have no idea how to represent $\mathfrak p$ as they don't define prime ideals of these kind of direct products anywhere in the book? This leads me to think that there is another way to approach the problem rather than showing these inclusions?

As a second question, what is this "canonical" homeomorphism between $X_i$ and $\operatorname{Spec} A_i$? It's also not defined anywhere in the book...

Comment: Hint: show an ideal $I$ in the product $A$ is a direct product $I=I_1\times \cdots \times I_n$ of ideals $I_i\subset A_i$. Then, consider the quotient $A/I$. When is this a domain? (note the multiplication in $A\times B$ is given by $(a,b)*(c,d)=(ac,bd)$).

Comment: Let $e_i=(0,\dots,1,\dots,0)$ with $1$ is the $i$th position, also let $e_i'=\sum_{j\ne i}e_j=(1,\dots,0,\dots,1)$. Then, $e_ie_i'=0\in\mathfrak p$ implies $e_i\in\mathfrak p$ or $e_i'\in\mathfrak p$. So, there exists $i$ such that $e_i'$ (and thus $e_j$ for $j\ne i$) belongs to $\mathfrak p$. Then, apply the correspondence of prime ideals between $A$ and $A/\prod_{j\ne i}A_j\cong A_i$.